# iPhone HTML5 font size

Tags: iphone, html, fonts

I am making html5 pages to be loaded on iPhone. And have a question about font sizing.

For example: some text has font size 20px. If I load this text 3g device font size if ok. When I load the same page on 4g (higher resolution) - the font looks the same size. I would expect font to be smaller, as resolution is higher.

May I ask you to explain this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't quite work like that.

Devices in iOS have a 'scale factor'. This is the number of pixels on the screen that correspond to a single point. Both the iPhone 3G and iPhone 4 have a screen that is 320x480 ***points***. However, the iPhone 4 has a scale factor of 2, so its *pixel size* is 640x960.

iOS is clever enough to figure out that if you're explicitly setting a pixel size in HTML you probably want it scaled up for a retina display. So it multiplies the pixel dimension by the scale factor of the screen (which is 2). Your 20 pixel font is rendered as if it was a 40 pixel font.

If you particularly care about providing two different styles for retina and non-retina it's possible to detect it in mobile safari. See here for more info: http://blog.iwalt.com/2010/06/targeting-the-iphone-4-retina-display-with-css3-media-queries.html

Comment: Thank you. Does the same rules apply for Android devices? I mean if I have text size 20px - will it be the same visual size for all devices?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure: I'm an iOS developer by trade. I would imagine so, but there's much more variance in terms of dimensions on that platform anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use class in in your tag then it is possible to set the size of text.

```
#content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #111;
    text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #555;
    font-family: 'Lobster', arial, serif;
}
```